# osmdroid rendering issue, zoom 16 rendering like 15

Tags: android, ios, osmdroid

I am rendering a map using osm droid(basic mode, I havent tweaked anything) and a map tile source rendered from Maperitive and bundled in a database where i am doing queries for the blobs. The problem is I have a friend developing an iOS app using the iOS Mapbox SDK with the same tiles and the issue is this: how come with the same tile source his app renders zoom level 16 correctly and osm droid renders zoom level 16 like zoom level 15. In fact, i have only experienced correct rendering on a crappy small density screen. Anyone who can shed some light on this matter, and if something can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are experiencing [Issue 523](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=523). The map tiles are not scaled to screen density in osmdroid. So when you are looking at zoom level 16 on your density=2.0 device (like a Nexus 10 for instance) it will look half the size as the iOS Mapbox which is probably scaling the tiles.

Comment: that seems to be it! it looks like it hasn't been fixed though, any workarounds you've done or any kind of solutions, adding an extra zoom level really isn't an option for me.